# explicit realization of irreducible representations of simple lie algebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I know explicit realization of irreducible representations of simple lie algebra $sl_n$ when the highest weight of that representation is a fundamental weight.Is there any explicit realization of any irreducible representation when the highest weight is not a fundamental weight?